# Two tags for Latin

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

At the moment, we have tags [latin](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) and [latin-language](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-language), both on the Latin language. They're not synonyms of one another. Shouldn't they be merged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch.

I've remapped [latin](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) into [latin-language](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-language) and synonymised them.